# Finding Volume and Bounds of Triple Intergral

Tags: cylindrical-coordinates

So I am looking to solve the triple integral using cylindrical coordinates. I believe this is quite simple however I am getting my bounds of integration confused.

The triple integral x^2+y^2+z^2 is defined by x^2+y^2<=1 and |z|<=1.

From this i have drawn up my cylinder and determined that the radius is 1 centred about the origin with the z axis ranging from -1

Now setting up the triple intergral is where I am getting confused also.

I know x=rcos(theta), y=rsin(theta) and z=z.

From here I am unsure how to proceed in setting up the triple integral. I think my understanding about how to incorporate the correct set up into the cylindrical coordinate system is what's making me lack.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

The set up is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta \int_{-1}^1 dz \int_{0}^1 f(r,\theta,z)\,r\,dr$$

Comment: When I set it up I used rdrdθdz. Essentially I have a triple integral with bounds -1<z<1 , 0<theta<2pi and 0<r<1.  Now what I don't get is the f(r,theta,z) component. Do I put in x^2 + y^2 +z^2 or do I just intergrate rdrdθdz over my bounds of integration?

Comment: @MagicMagician  $f(r,\theta,z)$ represents the function $x^2+y^2+z^2$ to integrate, we need to rewrite that in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: How can I go about converting that function into cylindrical coordiantes?

Also I used r dr dtheta dz. So so my order of integration was different to yours. Does that make a difference?

Comment: @MagicMagician In cylindrical coordinates $x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2+z^2$

Comment: @MagicMagician If you are looking for the volume of the region then of course $f=1$.

Comment: Yep I’m aware of that. But once again where I’m stuck is I know the boundary conditions of r and z. From that do we suppose that 1+sqrt(-x^2-y^2) is the original function in cylindrical coordinates

Comment: am I correct above?

Comment: @MagicMagician What is now $1+sqrt(-x^2-y^2) $? please refer to a given problem at once. Are you referring to the OP?